# how are multiple wallets associated with a single seed phrase?

Tags: wallet

could someone explain how a seed phrase on can be used to generate / restore multiple wallets?

I understand a the secret key is a public/private keypair, but how is a single seed phrase associated with multiple wallets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses BIP39 to transorm the mnemonic phrase into a private key and BIP32 to compute hierarchical deterministic wallets (HD wallets) from it.

https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki

then

https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki

This image illustrate the one way process going from the master seed to the wallet addresses.
[image]

https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032/derivation.png

So at the end there is a private key corresponding to each public key, but it doesn't have to be stored since it can be derived again next time we need it.